# Use static string from objective c in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

If in objective c I have a string declared in a header file on it's own, for example

```
static NSString* my_static_string = @"Hello world";
```

I am able to use it in swift and Xcode recognises it, however when I try to build I get "undefined symbol _my_static_string ..."

Is there any way I can use this string in swift?

Comment: In what context are you using this `static`? The `static` keyword has different meanings in different contexts, so you have to be more specific as to how you're using it.

Comment: It's on it's own in a header file. Question updated

Answer (score 4):

The `static` keyword, when used with a global, limits the scope of the variable to the current `.m` file. It's generally used when defining a constant used within a particular `.m` file, but not to be referenced elsewhere.

It doesn't quite make sense to do that if you're defining a constant in a `.h` file. In that case, you usually define the variable in one of the `.m` files:

```
NSString * const kMyConstant = @"Hello world";
```

and then in the `.h` file you define the external reference to this object:

```
extern NSString * const kMyConstant;
```

If you use the above pattern, if the `.h` file is included in the bridging header, you should then be able to use the `kMyConstant` constant in your Swift code.